# PHP - repeate character X times with delimiter

Tags: php

I want to create string: `?,?,?` where I want to specify how many times will character `?` repeat and what delimiter `,` will be.

Is there more readable way than:

```
trim(str_repeat('?,', 3), ',')
```

Comment: What do you mean by "more readable"? This looks perfectly readable to me. If you use `rtrim()` then I do not think it could be done much better.

Comment: I dislike idea to "create string and then clean it a bit". I wanted to skip cleaning part. Code may be longer but it is easier to process mentally. (at least for me). Look at @hsz answer.

Comment: Why? It has no effect on performance, and it is short and simple to understand. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It has effect on performance of programer. Code is not only for computer to process, but also for programers to read.

Comment: Your code could not be much simpler to read... "Trim this repeated string". Do you have dyslexia?

Comment: Thank you for compliment. We are slipping into discusion about different tastes (to trim or not to trim?) but that's not why I came here. I came here to discuss technical solution of my taste, not to discuss about whether my taste is good or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try with:

```
implode(',', array_fill(0, 3, '?'))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ment!